# Pandas Slicing a String using a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Hopefully you can help with this question. In the dataframe above (Temp column) I'm trying to extract the second value after the dash. I know I can use .split or .extract, however I would prefer to use a variable (in column DashPos) using slicing.

I have tried converting to float then int64 or Int64 but to no avail.

I would like to use the value in df['DashPos'] i.e. df['SecondPos'] = df.Temp.str[df.DashPos:]
however this gives the error slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method.

Any help would be very much appreciated. The Dataframe and code is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name':['Tom','Phil','Eric'],
'Alias':['T','P','E'],
'ID':[1,2,3],
'Age':[32,30,45],
'Temp':['100-200','200-300','200-300'],
'SSDashPos':[4,4,4]
              })

df= df.astype({'Temp':'string'})
df['DashPos'] = df.Temp.str.find('-').add(1)
df['SecondPos'] = df.Temp.str[df.DashPos:]
```

Many Thanks

Steven

Comment: And you're absolutely sure you don't want `df['Temp'].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[1])`?

Comment: Here's one way you could do it, but I'd use the apply here: `df['SecondPos'] = [rangestr[spot:] for rangestr, spot in zip(df.Temp, df['DashPos'])]`

Comment: you can also do `df['SecondPos'] = df.Temp.str.partition('-').loc[:,2]`

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is by using apply on a lambda function on axis=1.

```
df['SecondPos'] = df.apply(lambda x:x.Temp[x.DashPos:],axis=1)
```

When using apply method on axis=1, the function receives as an input a pandas Series corresponding to a row of the Dataframe df. So for each row the lambda function takes the value in column `Temp` and apply the slice based upon the value stored in column `DashPos`.

Does it help ?